# Get the column label of a DataFrame in pandas when a condition evaluates as True

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replicate the function of `DataFrame.idxmax()` and `DataFrame.idxmin()` but instead of min or max, I want to use an a custom function to evaluate.

For example in DataFrame D:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|   |  A  |  B  |  C  |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 0 | NaN | 100 | NaN |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 1 | 100 | NaN | NaN |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| 2 | NaN | NaN | 200 |
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Only one column will not be null containing a integer. I want to return a series S (with an index i) when the number is equal to 100:

```
+---+---+
| 0 | B |
+---+---+
| 1 | A |
+---+---+
```

I was hoping `D.apply(lambda x: x[x==100].index,1)` would work but it doesn't. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [66]: df[df==100].stack()
Out[66]: 
0  B    100
1  A    100
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But since I'm only interested in the values in the multiIndex, I added to your solution >> `c = pandas.Series(df[df==100].stack().index.get_level_values(1), index=df[df==100].stack().index.get_level_values(0))`. If you know a shorter way to do this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[np.nan, np.nan, 100], "B":[np.nan, 100, np.nan], "C":[100, np.nan, np.nan]})
df.unstack().dropna()
```

or:

```
df[df==100].unstack().dropna()
```

if you only need the index:

```
df.unstack().dropna().reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```